# Transform a pandas MultiIndex to a single Index using indention

Tags: python, pandas

I have a `pandas.DataFrame` with a `pandas.MultiIndex` like this:

```
                     Vals
Fruits     Apples       a
           Banana       b
Vegetables Tomato       c
           Onion        d
           Potato       e
Foobar     LoreIpsum    f
```

I want to transform it into this using a single index only:

```
               Vals
Fruits
    Apples        a
    Banana        b
Vegetables
    Tomato        c
    Onion         d
    Potato        e
Foobar
    LoreIpsmum    f
```

- New rows are inserted based on the first level.
- The values in the second level got and indention by 4 chars.

I can imagine how to "hack" this with a lot of if-then-else and for-loops. But I assume that there is an easier pandas way to do it.

Here is a full MWE

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import pandas as pd

midx = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([
    ('Fruits', 'Apples'),
    ('Fruits', 'Banana'),
    ('Vegetables', 'Tomato'),
    ('Vegetables', 'Onion'),
    ('Vegetables', 'Potato'),
    ('Foobar', 'LoreIpsum')
])
df = pd.DataFrame({'Vals': list('abcdef')}, index=midx)
print(df.to_markdown())

exp_idx = pd.Index([
    'Fruits',
    '    Apples',
    '    Banana',
    'Vegetables',
    '    Tomato',
    '    Onion',
    '    Potato',
    'Foobar',
    '    LoreIpsmum',
])
exp_df = pd.DataFrame({'Vals': list(' ab cde f')}, index=exp_idx)
print(exp_df.to_markdown())
```

Comment: Is your goal here purely for display purposes or is there some broader context?

Comment: Kind of display. I do use the resulting DataFrame and create a MS Word table out of it with my own library.

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is to create an MS Word table programmatically (as you mentioned in a comment that you are using your own library) it might be easier to simply reset the index:

```
df.reset_index()

      level_0    level_1 Vals
0      Fruits     Apples    a
1      Fruits     Banana    b
2  Vegetables     Tomato    c
3  Vegetables      Onion    d
4  Vegetables     Potato    e
5      Foobar  LoreIpsum    f
```

Then you can print your `level_O` index, create a new line and indent, print all the level_1 and Vals, and at each row check if `level_0` has changed. If not keep printing level_1 with the indent, if yes then print the new `level_0` index.

Does your library rely on the `to_markdown` formatting to work?

**EDIT: Additional Steps (modified)**

After re-reading your prompt I realised I didn't give you the solution you wanted: here is something that works.

```
# we reset the index as mentioned above
df = df.reset_index()

# then find all the duplicates in the zeroth level
mask = df.level_0.duplicated().values

# and we remove the duplicates
df.level_0[mask] = '' 

# then we create mystring which will hold the index styled the way you want
mystring = ""


for i in range(df.shape[0]):   
   # foor each row we get the level 0 and level 1 index
   str0, str1 = df.level_0.iloc[i], df.level_1.iloc[i]  

   # if the level 0 exists (it wasn't a duplicate)
   # we make sure to add it into the string
   if str0:  
     mystring += f"'{df.level_0.iloc[i]}','    {df.level_1.iloc[i]}',"  

   # if not we only add the level 1 index 
   # and we ensure there are 4 leading spaces as you wanted
    else:  
       mystring += f"'    {df.level_1.iloc[i]}',"
```

This gives the following string:

```
'Fruits','    Apples','    Banana','Vegetables','    Tomato','    Onion','    Potato','Foobar','    LoreIpsum',"
```

It didnt' look like you had a new line character in your formating but you can add one easily.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your solution. Can you provide more code please? It doesn't rely on markdown. See class `DocxDocument` in [`buhtzology.report`](https://buhtzology.readthedocs.io/en/develop/buhtzology.report.html).

Comment: I've updated my solution - if you want to add an end of line character add \n after the last comma on each f-string :)

Comment: Sorry, but this isn't a solution. My question is not only about the index but also about the dataframe. You have to take care of the extra rows that need to be added to the df. That is what my question makes complicated. FUsion two string arrays into one isn't a big deal.

Comment: And you want these extra rows to have null vals ? (Based on your example)

Comment: Correct "based on my example". That is why I provided the expected output.